# How do I find instances with a given number of related objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, activerecord, hash

I have an array of hashes called messages:

```
messages = [{ "id" => "1", "name" => "John", "content" => "xxxxx", "product" => "1" },
 { "id" => "2", "name" => "John", "content" => "yyyyy", "product" => "3" },
 { "id" => "3", "name" => "Paul", "content" => "zzzzzz", "product" => "3" },
 { "id" => "4", "name" => "George", "content" => "xxyyzz", "product" => "2" }]
```

The messages belong to a product:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :product
end
```

How can I find the products with a given number of messages? e.g. find products with messages > 1 would give product "3"

Comment: Are you looking for just the id for the product(s) or the actual object? i.e. ["3"] just an array with product id or Product.find(3)?

Comment: That's it I need the actual object, like Product.find(3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group messages by product, and select products with more than one message.

`messages.group_by(|m| m['product']).select{|p, mList| mList.length() > 1}.keys()`

If you want to retrieve Product instances from DB, use ActiveRecord methods:

`Product.joins(:messages).group("id").having("count(*) > 1")`

Comment: Ah you beat me by 39 seconds. I defer to your timeliness.

Comment: OK and if I need to get the actual products, does that work:
`Product.each{|prod| prod.messages.group_by(|m| m['product']).select{|p, mList| mList.length() > 1}.keys()}`

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is the following:

```
prod_ids = messages.map{|m| m["product"]}.uniq
prod_ids.select {|prod| prod_ids.count(prod) > 1}
```

That is; extract an array of the product numbers, remove duplicates. Then choose from that array those numbers which appear in the array more than once.